# Does Python have sync?

Tags: python, linux, synchronization

The [sync man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sync) says:

> sync() causes all buffered modifications to file metadata and data to
>   be written to the underlying file systems.

Does Python have a call to do this?

P.S. Not [fsync](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.fsync), I see that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Python 3.3 has os.sync, see [the docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.sync). The [source](http://hg.python.org/releasing/3.3.1/file/8e5812b35480/Modules/posixmodule.c#l3062) confirms it is the same thing.

For Python 2 you can to make an [external call](http://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) to the system:

```
from subprocess import check_call
check_call(['sync'])
```

Answer (score 14):

As said, Python 3.3 has the call - on Python 2.x, since it is a simple
system call, requiring no data to be passed back and forth, you can use ctypes to make the call:

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> libc = ctypes.CDLL("libc.so.6")
>>> libc.sync()
0
```

Comment: Whoa, fancy. :) I would be nervous that libc.so.6 might not always exist (although I am on UNIX), so probably subprocess or `sync` is the way for me.

Answer (score 7):

Combining the [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15983348/2015768) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15983693/2015768), I use the following at the top of my module:

```
if hasattr(os, 'sync'):
    sync = os.sync
else:
    import ctypes
    libc = ctypes.CDLL("libc.so.6")
    def sync():
        libc.sync()
```

Comment: Any particular reason for using `def sync()` instead of `sync = libc.sync`?

Comment: Ah actually there is, cannot be called with parameters by accident ;)