# Reduce a given larger file to specific file size in python

Tags: python, filesystems

I am trying to reduce a larger file to a given file size for my testing purpose. The code is as follows:

```
f = open ('original_file', 'rb')
f.seek(1000000)
rest = f.read()
f.close()
f1 = open('new_file', 'w')
f1.write(rest)
f1.close()
```

I want to reduce 1 MB from that file irrespective of content. But I am not able to get that reduction in the same file. Please help me where I am going wrong or any other method to reduce the content of the same file to specified MB. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To trim a file to a determined size, maintaining its begining, you can use the `os.truncate` call.

You don't mention whether you want to shave the bytes at the begining or at the ending of the file - but from your code, one deduces it is at the beggining.

In that case, since the common `truncate` call is available in some file-systens to clip the file just at the end, what one has to do is write the data from the desired position to the end at the beggining of the file. A compact way of doing that is simply opening the file twice - (in some O.S.s that might not work, just read the dta to a temporary object, and open the file again for writting, in that case):

```
import os

def truncate_begining(path, length):
    """Remove length bytes at the beggning of given file"""
    original_length = os.stat(path).st_size
    with open(path, "r+b") as reading, open(path, "r+b") as writting:
        reading.seek(length)
        writting.write(reading.read())
    try:
        os.truncate(path, orginal_length - length)
    except OSError as error:
        print("Unable to truncate the file:", error)
```

Note that the `truncate` functionality is not available in all circunstances, and that depends on the filesystem the file is on having this capability. If it does not have, a call to truncate will raise an error.  (The docs say the call is new in Python 3.3, and is available for Windows only on Python 3.5 onwards)

For Python versions prior to 3.3, on Linux, one can make use of  `ctypes` to call system's truncate directly:

```
import ctypes
libc = ctypes.CDLL("libc.so.6")
libc.truncate(<path>, <length>)
```

Comment: Is it available for python 2.7? Thanks.

Comment: No, this is a new thing in Python 3.3 - it should be possible to make the system call to the O.S> directly using ctypes in Python 2.7.

But if you have a script to do just this  (even if it does a lot more things), why not use Python 3.6?

Comment: The current framework supports Python 2.7. Making changes for this arrangement would be difficult. Thanks

Comment: I see - so there is a lot more code - well, I will check if I can come u with a ctypes example. Which OS is it? I think I cn only provide an easy example for Linux.

Comment: there it is. Based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15983272/does-python-have-sync/15983693#15983693 .